# How to make foreach loop through List<contact>?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, t-sql, foreach

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Insert List<contacts> to table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13422702/insert-listcontacts-to-table)

I have `List<Contacts>` I want to loop through that list to add to the database using a stored procedure. But my `foreach` loop will only insert the first contact in the list. How can I make it call the stored procedure to insert all the contacts?

```
private static bool Insert_company_contacts(int companyID, List<Contacts> contacts)
{
    // get a configured DbCommand object
    DbCommand comm = GenericDataAccess.CreateCommand();

    // Set the stored procedure name 
    comm.CommandText = "AddContacts";

    // Company Info
    foreach (var c in contacts)
    {
        // create new parameter @LabelContactTypeID
        DbParameter param = comm.CreateParameter();
        param.ParameterName = "@CompanyID";
        param.Value = companyID;
        param.DbType = DbType.Int32;
        comm.Parameters.Add(param);

        // create new parameter @LabelContactTypeID
        param = comm.CreateParameter();
        param.ParameterName = "@LabelContactTypeID";
        param.Value = c.LabelContactTypeID;
        param.DbType = DbType.Int32;
        comm.Parameters.Add(param);

        // create new parameter @ContactDetails
        param = comm.CreateParameter();
        param.ParameterName = "@ContactDetails";
        param.Value = c.ContactDetail;
        param.DbType = DbType.StringFixedLength;
        comm.Parameters.Add(param);

        // create new parameter @Status
        param = comm.CreateParameter();
        param.ParameterName = "@Status";
        param.Value = c.Status;
        param.DbType = DbType.Boolean;
        comm.Parameters.Add(param);

        // create new parameter @Notes
        param = comm.CreateParameter();
        param.ParameterName = "@Notes";
        param.Value = c.Notes;
        param.DbType = DbType.StringFixedLength;
        comm.Parameters.Add(param);

        try
        {
            if (GenericDataAccess.ExecuteNonQuery(comm) == -1)  
                return false;
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Well, you're almost certainly getting an exception. Remove the `try...catch` block, and let us know what the exception is. £50 says you are closing your connection after the first write to the database though :)

Comment: This coding style -- try/catch with a success/failure return code -- is dated and bad. You get no information about what went wrong and you can thus do nothing to deal with the problem adequately.

Comment: Or his call to `ExecuteNonQuery()` returns `-1`.  Can the OP put a break point in there and figure out which is happening?

Answer (score 1):

You are creating a single `DbCommand` in front of the loop and inside your loop you add the parameters. So in the second iteration, you add a whole new set of parameters to your command.

Just move the creation of the parameter outside the loop like this:

```
DbCommand comm = GenericDataAccess.CreateCommand();
//Set the store Proc name 
comm.CommandText = "AddContacts";

DbParameter paramDetails = comm.CreateParameter();
comm.Parameters.Add(paramDetails);
// add other parameters ...

foreach (var c in contacts)
{
    // in the loop, just update parameter values and execute the command
    paramDetails.Value = c.ContactDetail;
    GenericDataAccess.ExecuteNonQuery(comm)
}
```

In addition, you shouldn't ignore the exception details when catching an exception as you do.
If you don't handle the exception its better not to catch it at all.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you put a return? When C# meet a RETURN, it quit the function, stopping the iteration.

Use another way to know what happen. Personally, I user the modified Rows numbers,

Comment: The `return false` is only executed on error situations (which probably is what happens)